# C# in VS2005: is there set style notation for integers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, set

For C# in VS2005, can you do something like this:

```
if number in [1,2..10,12] { ... }
```

which would check if `number` is contained in the set defined in the square brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "kind of" do what you want using the [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method:

```
if (Enumerable.Range(2, 8).Concat(new [] { 1, 12 }).Contains(number)) {
    ....
}
```

Of course, that's not nearly as readable as what you find in a basic functional language...

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 (which is what VS 2005 targets) doesn't have the notion of a `Set`.

.NET 3.5 introduced `HashSet<T>`, and .NET 4 introduced `SortedSet<T>`.

There isn't a literal form for them though - although collection initializers provide something *slightly* similar:

```
new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 4, 12 }
```

Of course, you *could* just use an array:

```
int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 12 };
```

but the *range* part of your sample - `2..10` - doesn't exist in any version of C#.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.

However, you can use the `Contains()` method of a `List<int>`:

```
List<int> numbers = ...
if (numbers.Contains(2)) { ... }
```

if `numbers` is an array, you can either initialize a new `List<int>` with the array values:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> newList = new List<int>(numbers);
if (newList.Contains(2)) { ... }
```

or use [`Array.Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be.aspx):

```
Array.Exists(numbers, delegate(int i) { return i == 2; });
```

Comment: According to me there was no Linq available in C#2.0 (VS2005).